# How to show html template using inline styles only?

Tags: html, css-selectors

I want to display html template in a webpage. The styles of that template is specified inline.
But when i try to display it in my webpage, some styles that are defined in my css are adding into it and the template is not displayed properly. This template is used to create mails and when i send this template as mail to my gmail account it is displayed correctly. How its done in gmail? How they show the template using inline styles only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the tinymce editor. I used tinymce editor in read mode and displayed the html template in it. I dont know whether its correct method or not. But it was perfect for my requirement. Thanks Greg for your reply..:)

Answer (score 1):

The question is actually pretty clear. I think you're looking for an iframe tag. That will allow you to display a document within another page, with its own independent style.

One thing to add: if you ever wonder how another site does something, just install firebug (on Firefox) and check out their source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using jsp and jstl tags to obtain the content of the template. So i think i cant use the iframe for my use.I solved the problem by using the tinymce editor in read only mode and displayed the template in my webpage.